# Git config branch rebase true by pattern instead of name

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull, git-config

Git documentation have the following:

```
branch.<name>.rebase
When true, rebase the branch <name> on top of the fetched branch, instead of merging the default branch from the default remote when "git pull" is run. See "pull.rebase" for doing this in a non branch-specific manner.
```

If I'm using the name of that branch everything is perfect, but I want to apply this option for the set of branches with the common pattern, for example 'feature-branch-*', these branches will be short lived and I don't want to manage it's configuration separately in git config.

Does anybody know the way how to do that or this is not possible?

Comment: Have you tried it with a pattern in a dummy repo to see what happens?

Comment: I tried on the sample project with the config `git config feature-branch-*.rebase true`, but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a glob pattern `branch.prefix-*.rebase` with msysgit version 1.8.3, and it didn't work, so at least for that version of Git, you have to use an exact name.